# SASS @for loop output CSS as one block of code?

Tags: sass

**I have the following for loop:**

```
@for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .tile#{$i}.noMargin {  
    margin:0;
     }
}
```

**Which outputs as:**

```
 .threeColForm .tile1.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile2.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile3.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile4.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile5.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile6.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile7.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile8.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile9.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile10.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile11.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
.threeColForm .tile12.noMargin {
  margin: 0; }
```

**Is there a way to write this so it would ouput like this:**

```
.threeColForm .tile1.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile2.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile3.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile4.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile5.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile6.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile7.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile8.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile9.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile10.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile11.noMargin,
.threeColForm .tile12.noMargin {
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**MY CSS (FYI):**

```
.threeColForm {
    //cols, gutter
    @include grid(12, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `@extend`

```
$columns: 12;

%no-margin {
    margin: 0;
}

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .tile#{$i}.noMargin {  
        @extend %no-margin;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.tile1.noMargin, .tile2.noMargin, .tile3.noMargin, .tile4.noMargin, .tile5.noMargin, .tile6.noMargin, .tile7.noMargin, .tile8.noMargin, .tile9.noMargin, .tile10.noMargin, .tile11.noMargin, .tile12.noMargin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That works great. Could you explain what the % before no-margin does?

Comment: It's called a *placeholder selector*:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders