# How to combine a SASS list into multiple selectors

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I have several page classes on my page:

```
.page1, page2, .page3
```

and so on.

I would like to have selectors for permutations of them:

```
.page1-foo, page2-foo, .page3-foo
.page1-bar, page2-bar, .page3-bar
```

How would I do that in SASS?

I tried doing:

```
$pages: (page1, page2, page3);

@each $page in $pages {
  .#{$page}-foo {
     // some css
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
.page1-foo {
    // some css
}

.page2-foo {
    // some css
}

.page3-foo {
    // some css
}
```

But I can't find a solution combining the classes to a single selector...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593917/sass-for-loop-output-css-as-one-block-of-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout my variant:

```
$pages: (page1, page2, page3);

%styles{
  color: #fff;
}

@each $page in $pages {
  .#{$page}-foo {
     @extend %styles;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is preferred that duplicates be closed as duplicates, rather than be answered.